# HTTP ports and browsers

Tags: http, browser, port

I have a question about HTTP, if in one computer run 3 different browser and they all go to the same server HTTP (same website). As client HTTP they all have different port number or all the same? And what about the Tabs?

Answer (score 0):

Destination port is the same. Source port of connections are different for any browser and any tab.
you can control RFC 2616 for specifications.